# Why does my integral not evaluate?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I just started using *Mathematica* today, so I'm sure there is something I am doing incorrectly. I am trying to evaluate this integral:

```
Integrate[(2*A*r - ((2*B)/r^3) + (d/r)), {r, p, q}]
```

Where `A`, `B` and `d` are constants and `p` and `q` are my bounds of integration. How can I get it to evaluate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mathematica* seems to get lost in the complex plane here. Assumptions help:

```
Integrate[(2*A*r - ((2*B)/r^3) + (d/r)), {r, p, q}, 
 Assumptions -> A > 0 && B > 0 && p > 0 && p < q]
```

yielding:

```
B (-(1/p^2) + 1/q^2) + A (-p^2 + q^2) + d Log[q/p]
```

Comment: Ah ok, didnt know about adding assumptions! thanks! worked great

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to calculate the integral and then plug in the limits of integration:

```
int = Integrate[(2*A*r - ((2*B)/r^3) + (d/r)), r];
FullSimplify[(int /. r -> q) - (int /. r -> p)]

-((B + A p^4)/p^2) + B/q^2 + A q^2 - d Log[p] + d Log[q]
```

(Thanks to @theorist for noting I'd switched the p's and q's.)

Comment: I think you meant `FullSimplify[(int /. r -> q) - (int /. r -> p)]`